# How to make Windows 10 input suggestions panel dark?

Tags: windows, chinese, ime, dark-mode, chinese-input-method

I use Microsoft Pinyin to input Chinese
Although my system theme is set to dark, my pinyin IME is light

[image: Photo of my IME]

Comment: @Peregrino69 isn't the IME part of the OS? I was not aware this was a web app.